# File Manager not found when share chooser shown from an android app

Tags: android, android-intent, file-manager, android-intent-chooser

How to make my file manager can be shown from this sharing chooser? 
So I can save the image without any third party like `EZ`, `X-Plore`, `ZArchiver`

[image]
[image]

I have tried like this.

```
    val uris: List<Uri> = listOf(
"content://com.myapp.app.provider/external_files/Android/data/com.myapp.app/files/Documents/1646536571838.jpg", 
"content://com.myapp.app.provider/external_files/Android/data/com.myapp.app/files/Documents/1646536571840.jpg", 
"content://com.myapp.app.provider/external_files/Android/data/com.myapp.app/files/Documents/1646536571842.jpg"
    )
    val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
        putParcelableArrayListExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            uris
        )
        type = "image/*"
    }

    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send to"))
```

I want to share and select File Manager, so my image can be view in gallery

Comment: In your manifest file you give an activity an intent-filter that matches the used intent.

Comment: But.. Your own app does not have to react on its own intents. Why would you?

Comment: `So I can save the image without any third party` ? Which image? Every app can save images. What do you mean?

Comment: @blackapps What is contains `intent-filter` in manifest?

Comment: @blackapps image from `myUris` contain image link

Comment: You have no image itself? Only a link to an image? You have an image url? Please tell how such an url looks like.

Comment: I update my post

Comment: Ok. It looks that you do not want to save an image or images. It looks as if you wanna share some images. And those images are already -saved- on your device. You want to share them using a file provider. Please elaborate/updat your post.

Comment: Yes, but it not show on gallery. I just want copy my image into public directory. so user can see their image into gallery

Comment: All what you wrote in your post an said before has nothing to do with making an existable image visible in what you call 'Gallery'. This is new. You should try again and write a post that tells what you want.